# iPad showing the iPhone storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have added two storyboards in my project. 1 is for iPhone and 1 is for iPad. I also added key in Info file with both storyboard names.

When I run the app in iPad it shows main storyboad instead of storyboardipad

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: question is that when i run app in ipad it shows main storyboad instead of storyboardipad?

Comment: i had already said in my question what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change "Main storyboard file base name" to "Main storyboard file base name (iPhone)"

Comment: Tell me what you have in Build Settings under Target Device Family.

Comment: Go to Build Settings panel on you target and find Targeted Device Family setting. Tell me what it has.

Comment: there is nothing like target device family setting in build setting , i m using xcode 7

Comment: Sorry, TargetED Device Family. I have edited already previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90733/discussion-between-kirander-and-asad-ali).